# Mystery "Error establishing database connection" error message on Google Compute Engine

Tags: mysql, wordpress, google-compute-engine

I'm running Wordpress on a Google Compute Engine instance.  Op system is Debian, Db is MySql 5.5.4.6, php 5.6.14...

Earlier today, I noticed my site using 90% CPU. Went to investigate by opening the google ssh shell from the google cloud platform console, but couldn't.  Examined the Serial Output log and saw a message indicating that the disk was full and this was preventing me from logging in.  Since running on Debian, I bumped up the allocated space on the SSD persistent disk from 10GB to 50GB.  I checked the files system and saw the 50GB.  I restarted the app instance and received the error in the subject line.  I then restarted the DB instance and app instance, but this still did not clear the error.  The DB credentials in the wp-config.php file have not changed since when it was working ok two days ago.  When I try accessing mysql from the command line using root and its password, I get an Error 1040 "Too many connections"... when I try the command mysql status, I get the same error 1040...  Am at a loss as to what could be causing the issue - could it be some sort of caching thing?  Any suggestions as to how to proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: According to different blogs the error ¨too many connections¨ could be misleading and still be related to disk space [1](https://x10hosting.com/community/threads/sql-error-mysql4-too-many-connections-1040.182280/),[2](http://www.microshell.com/database/mysql/mysql-too-many-connection-errors/). After resizing, did you check the space of file system using ¨df -h¨? Some OS need to be manually re-partitioned after resizing the disk [3](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-root-persistent-disks#manualrepartition).

Answer (score 1):

For [GCE Debian OS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-root-persistent-disks#repartitionrootpd), after changing the size of the disk using Google Cloud Console or `gcloud` command, it would be required to reboot the VM to performs an automatic disk resizing. After reboot, connect to VM via SSH and use `df -h` command to verify the size of the disk.

About `Too many connections` error, due to insufficient resources there might be an excessive amount of half-open connections to your database that need to be terminated. A VM reboot should resolve this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL most likely shut down incorrectly when disk space ran out. You need to repair the database with `myisamchk` tool, if you are using MyISAM tables:

```
myisamchk -r /path/to/database/*.MYI
```

For InnoDB tables, you can use instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html

Answer (score -2):

i had a similar problem recently when trying to view the wordpress site in a browser i received an Error establishing database connection” error message. to resolve it i logged into my on Google Compute Engine and stopped the vm , then once it had stopped started it again and miraculously it worked my site was up and running again